# C# Xamarin editText click on button and then scroll to listview item, how?

Tags: c#, android, listview, scroll, xamarin

I made a huge listview list, now I want to make this user friendly. So when I type something in a edittext and when I click on the button: then It needs to scroll programmatically to the listview item. How can I do this?

Comment: You could try the smoothscrollbyoffset method, you can find documenation here, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.ListView.SmoothScrollByOffset/p/System.Int32/

Comment: How does this method work?

Comment: SmoothScrollBy Offset is with int, but I need to get to the text item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you finish typing you need to search that text in your list and smoothscroll to that position.

```
private ListView _listView;
private ArrayAdapter<string> _adapter;
private EditText _inputSearch;
private Button _buttonSearch;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);    
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    string[] products = {"Winter Is Coming", "The Kingsroad", "Lord Snow", "Cripples, Bastards, and Broken Things", "The Wolf and the Lion", "A Golden Crown", "You Win or You Die", "The Pointy End", "Baelor", "Fire and Blood"};

    _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list_view);
    _inputSearch = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputSearch);
    _buttonSearch = FindViewById< EditText > (Resource.Id.btnSearch);
    _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, Resource.Id.product_name, products);
    _listView.Adapter = _adapter;

    _buttonSearch.Click += (sender, e) => 
    {             
        var index = Array.FindIndex(products, i => i.Equals(_inputSearch.Text));
        _listView.SmoothScrollToPosition(index);
    };    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! I will test this wednesday on school, so you will hear from me.

Comment: I'm going to test it wednesday, so when it's work I will mark it.

Comment: It's half right, because when I type something it will scroll, but when I search for: 'cinnamon', then listview automatic scrolls to currant.

Comment: Currant is the first item with: 'C'

Comment: In that case its a question of logic in the Contains. But the original question I answered correctly.

Comment: I made equals of it, but your answer is not correct.

Comment: You asked how to scroll to a position in a scrollview. My answer responds to that. I tested it.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, but it's logic that when you type a write word, then it needs to scroll to the right word, instead of the first word with a: 'C'.

Comment: Change: 'Contains' into 'Equals'. Then it's perfect!

Comment: But thanks for you code, without you It didn't worked at all!

Comment: I changed the answer to match the equals. Thank you.